# How to connect to a remote database in a digital ocean server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, digital-ocean

I have a rails application in a windows local machine and i have a postgresql remote database in digital ocean server [ubuntu server]. How to connect it, I tried like this:

database.yml

```
default: &default
adapter: postgresql
encoding: unicode
host: xxx.xxx.xxx.xx
username: username 
password: password
schema_search_path: "public,shared_extensions"

# For details on connection pooling, see Rails configuration guide
# http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#database-pooling
pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>

development:
 <<: *default
 database: database_name
```

When i restarted my server i get error
`could not connect to server: Connection timed out (0x0000274C/10060) Is the server running on host "xxx.xxx.xxx.xx" and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?`

am i doing the right procedure? can anyone get me through this?

Comment: Yes, That's right. Just make sure that your database server is running and accepting connections from other system.

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-do-i-connect-to-postgres-from-a-client-machine. Maybe this can help.

Comment: @KrupaSuthar thank you. i will check this out and update.

Comment: @KrupaSuthar do we need to add the password of the host server??? the password  given by digital ocean for droplet

Comment: i tried, still getting the same error.

Comment: Try to connect your db first with ssh or PGadmin if you can't access it then it must be something wrong with your db access

Comment: i tried with pgadmin still the same error

Comment: @KrupaSuthar i figured it out , we should open the port 5432 for tcp, i opened manually from the server by running the comman `ufw allow 5432/tcp`, thank you for  the link you shared it did some help.